# Computing the gcd of a relatively prime polynomial

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I was given a question that starts off like this.

Suppose that $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ and relatively prime.  For each of the following, if the answer must be one particular number, then compute it; otherwise, say that it cannot be determined.  Give a short proof of each of your answers.

- (a) $\gcd(a^{11}, b^{11})$

I generally know how to compute the $\gcd$ but for this question the exponents are completely throwing me off.

Comment: If $d$ is a divisor of $a$ and $b$, then $d^{11}$ is a divisor of $a^{11}, b^{11}$

Comment: What's the word *polynomial* got to do with any of this???

Answer (score 0):

using the fundamental theorem of arithmatic you write a and b as a product of powers of distinct primes. Hypothesis say nothing in common. If we rase to the 11th power still nothing in cimmon.